# I have been all the time since lunch

Tags: verbs, expressions, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I heard a native speaker say these words.
Looking at his watch, this gentleman said to someone:

> I have been all the time since lunch.

- What makes this sentence grammatical ?
- Is there more to it than meets the eye?

Comment: Was there an implied "doing something" after "have been"?. For example, did the other speaker just ask "have you been checking for e-mail from George recently?" In which case a comma after "been" would be appropriate.

Comment: Could there have been something said, by either the speaker here or his companion, prior to this statement? It doesn't make much sense on it's own, but could if there was a context that meant he had been [that thing] since lunch. "I feel like I'm going to be sick. I have been all the time since lunch." "Are you still trying to get her on the phone?" "I have been all the time since lunch."

Comment: we were at an airport, in queue, when I heard this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must have been a reply to a comment or question.

- "Are you going to think about it?"
- "I have been, all the time since lunch."

Otherwise, it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I just dont see the comma as necessary. As well, the comma could come after 'time'.